# Should I find/replace values in the_content?

Tags: the-content

I'm creating a plugin specialized for a website. Most of the pages are pretty general (blog posts, contact pages, etc...) but a handful of pages will have custom code (specific SQL) for display statistics.

I'm wondering, best practices and what-not, is is better to build the page with all of the code inside of a function and then replace `the_content` using the filter...*OR*...should I build the html inside of the page (using the basic WP admin pages) and do a replace at certain spots for variable values?

Does this make sense?

Comment: You could build a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), [filter the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), [include special templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) or [template parts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), or even all of them depending on your exact situation, which we don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shortcodes for that, that is exactly what they are for.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I've created shortcodes and placed them inside of my content and then replaced the content in the filter. *sigh*